# how to do a pentest to /assets/js/login.js

Tags: penetration-test, javascript, ctf

Hey guys this is my first question in this kind of platform. I made a pentest a vulnerable machine this is like a web page video content there are not much target vectors. In my attack a detect only two possible attack vectors an admin panel (http://vulnerabletarge.com/login) and GET parameter(this seems sanitized) in the search bar. I want a path clarification must be try to bypass login, brute force (there are not maxium number of attempts) or expand my content discovery list.

The js file have more than 1000 lines of code and in pure javascript dont have HTML body or head tags.

The login pages only have this

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://vulnerabletarget.com/assets/js/login.js"></script>
</body>
```

And show a login. I need a some help

Comment: Don't worry about the javascript.  Just run your browser through a proxy to record requests, see what requests/responses are sent and received, and change things until you make something break (in a good way)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's impossible to say something without seeing a source code or the originate web application.

Here I can only "blindly" suggest you only three things besides of brute-forcing the login form:

1. Try **SQL injection** in the login form. Some applications might be
   vulnerable to login bypass through SQLi.
2. Try to load this JS file to some **static security code analyzers**.
   It's not a big chance that it finds something, but you can try. Here
   is the list of security code analyzers collected by OWASP:
   https://owasp.org/www-community/Source_Code_Analysis_Tools
3. Try to **google** the parts of the JS source code. It can give you more
   information about the environment. There is a chance that this web
   app is using some software containing known vulnerabilities. Also
   try to find comments and copyrights within the JS code for the same
   purpose.